# How to distinguish between periodic and random impulse?

Tags: signal-detection

I am working for two signals. One is a dataset with 10 equally spaced impulses. Another is a dataset with randomly spaced impulses of identical length. The higher order moments, such as kurtosis, skewness or standard deviation are not sensitive to the two signals. Who can help look for an indicator to identify it?

Comment: A periodic impulse should be amenable to a time series analysis method whereas the random impulse would not.

Comment: Is the signal clean enough that you can use some kind of thresholding and difference the results to look for nearly equal differences? Or is it noisy enough that you need something more sophisticated to pull the pulses out of the mix (and perhaps to keep a single pulse from appearing to be multiple pulses)?

Comment: :Wayne filtering by differencing is a particular form of an autoregressive (ARIMA Model). Any filter that is used should be empirically identified and never assumed :see the Slutsky effect. For example if you difference a white noise process you create a series that is an MA(1) series. Your comment about injecting pulses and creating multiple pulses is to this point.

Answer (score 3):

The autocorrelation function(acf) of a random white noise signal will have an inpulse at zero,  and the acf will be zero at other times meaning there is no periodicity or correlation at time lags. The acf of a periodic function will have peaks based on the periodicities, and often have a pattern. This is a clear indicator to distinguish a white noise signal from a periodic signal.

Answer (score 0):

The "indicator to identify the deterministic pulses" is found by filtering the series for any autoregressive properties ; any level shifts , any local time trends , any "one-time pulses". The "cleansed series" can then be evaluated for the occurrence ( if any ) when thie phenomenon started. Please review some of my postings regarding INTERVENTION DETECTION , specifically the search for "SEASONAL PULSES" . You might review http://www.unc.edu/~jbhill/tsay.pdf and any and all material at http://www.autobox.com (particularly the AFS University material) for additional insights and help in this challenging area of time series analysis/prediction and signal analysis. For transparency purposes I should mention that I am one of the authors of AUTOBOX which speaks directly to the issue you raise. Hope this helps !